# JavaMail InputStream attachment takes forever

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, inputstream, attachment

I am trying to send an email with attachments. The attachment(s) is generated on-the-fly so there is no file and I can't create a temp file on the filesystem.

```
InputStream attachment
```

I have tried to use JavaMail directly and apache.commons.mail. With both I have the same result. It takes 6 min where the browser stays as "waiting for localhost". I suspect the problem is that the mail libraries don't really know how big the InputStream is (or they don't deal with InputStream properly) so they wait until some timeout and then the mail is sent. I have done tests with files (via FileDataSource and others) and it works fine, but not with InputStream...

**Is there any way to make it work without making the user wait forever?** Of course reducing the timeOut is not a good solution since I don't know how fast the connection will be and on the other hand I don't want to make fast users waiting for sending a 200KB email.

```
 // Create the email message
    MultiPartEmail email2 = new MultiPartEmail();
    email2.setHostName(host);
    email2.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator(username, password));
    email2.setSSLOnConnect(true);
    email2.setFrom(username);
    email2.setSmtpPort( Integer.parseInt(port) );
    email2.addTo(to);
    email2.setSubject("MAIL");
    email2.setMsg("Text");

    DataSource source = new ByteArrayDataSource(attachment, "application/pdf");  
    // add the attachment
    email2.attach(source, "somefile.pdf", "Description of some file");
    email2.send();
```

This code will send the mail correctly... but after 6 min or more.

**EDIT**

I have placed some traces in the code:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println("Start: " + dateFormat.format(date));
 // Create the email message
    MultiPartEmail email2 = new MultiPartEmail();
    email2.setHostName(host);
    email2.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator(username, password));
    email2.setSSLOnConnect(true);
    email2.setFrom(username);
    email2.setSmtpPort( Integer.parseInt(port) );
    email2.addTo(emailTO);
    email2.setSubject("MAIL");
    email2.setMsg("Text");
date = new Date();
System.out.println("Before DataSource: " + dateFormat.format(date));
    DataSource source = new ByteArrayDataSource(attachment, "application/pdf");  
date = new Date();
System.out.println("After DataSource: " + dateFormat.format(date));
    // add the attachment
    email2.attach(source, "somefile.pdf", "Description of some file");
date = new Date();
System.out.println("Before send(): " + dateFormat.format(date));
    email2.send();
date = new Date();
System.out.println("After send(): " + dateFormat.format(date));
```

And the result is this:

```
Start: 2014/02/24 16:18:01
Before DataSource: 2014/02/24 16:18:01
After DataSource: 2014/02/24 16:18:01
Before send(): 2014/02/24 16:18:01
Feb 24, 2014 4:18:01 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDXObjectImage getColorSpace
INFO: About to return NULL from unhandled branch. filter = COSName{DCTDecode}
After send(): 2014/02/24 16:26:35
```

If I comment the `email2.attach(...)` I get this:

```
Start: 2014/02/24 16:28:56
Before DataSource: 2014/02/24 16:28:56
After DataSource: 2014/02/24 16:28:56
Before send(): 2014/02/24 16:28:56
After send(): 2014/02/24 16:29:27
```

Of course it takes a long time, but it is kind of acceptable....

Now, it is clear the problem is related to the attachment. I am not sure what I am getting the PDFBox warning, though...

**EDIT 2**

I am now testing without attachment and it is taking barely 5 seconds to send the email... So it really looks something related to the way the InputStream is accessed.

**EDIT 3**

I enabled the debug and it seems that the time is consumed in the attachment. I see what send() does and prints:

```
------=_Part_0_2141791733.1395266799862
Content-Type: application/pdf; name="my.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="my.pdf"
Content-Description: 

JVBERi0xLjQKJfbk/N8KMSAwIG9iago8PAovTWFya0luZm8gMiAwIFIKL01ldGFkYXRhIDMgMCBS
```

... and then send() prints the attachment content little by little in chunks like this:

```
MhKxjVRnwA6I8BisAX1VTXc0hw1DXO0lBcQJDQpWFZPU3oX2YogU3Y0SbgFxKBCJWzUEqfJIQ5Bh
GrYDx1o3JOIYHZPnVRZHa4EA0FqGxiZk6MdkEfYakPO4MW1jXIjeKFMxdL1XY84nrGDMwoyCkC3N
TJOAJITplbIewNEXv6u8AIf64hiZIm+x4jyFOxzk5DzfSONJiDiKbtozF+Yz+g90lJOCLiRFneuV
3AYDQAD1gnW+odwoSVBAUezLL5Zwue1yttDySw5zVsaE9j7kv9mHpOlnTephlZR5fiu/f+XEOb/O
qQ6suP2zOl/3KRw+OMiXC5hNGlAca7d2XWDMLIiQs45yUsCnljRLVdYFKz7Zg6zcsiH9kaupwOe4
ifPEiXe/8LEok2So8o3Bp5XysDadYxsllfVLlNdLXlQc+2R+kdFHam5ydBm5HkYl5ZCwF2vPKpvU
```

Then it takes some seconds.. and prints another chunk. This process lasts around 6 min. until is finished:

```
MjRDODdCODVGMEEyQjBBMzVDQj4gPEM5MjBBRjU5Q0MxOEM2NDI5MDM4REIzMEI2OUE0REQ5Pl0K
L1Jvb3QgMSAwIFIKL0luZm8gNyAwIFIKL1hSZWZTdG0gMTYxOAo+PgpzdGFydHhyZWYKNDEzNjI5
CiUlRU9GCg==
------=_Part_0_690515382.1395264718480--
.
250 OK id=4WQO3h-0004D1-VQ
QUIT
221 mail2.... closing connection
```

I guess there is something wrong with the `InputStream`. With no attachment or getting the attachment from a file it works fine and fast. The attachment is only ~0.4MB

Perhaps there is something with the way the `InputStream` is created. However it seems strange because I use exactly the same method to download the PDF and the download works just fine.

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    pd.save(os);
    return new ByteArrayInputStream( os.toByteArray() );
```

Comment: Where does the InputStream come from? Have you actually established that the time is spent in send()? Rather than in constructing the ByteArrayDataSource for example?

Comment: I placed some logs and the time is spent in the send(). The INpuTStream comes from another function (also created by me) that generates a PDF on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly which statement is taking all the time?  Is it creating the ByteArrayDataSource?  Or is it the send method?  ByteArrayDataSource copies all the data immediately into a byte array.  If that's where all the time is, you might be able to do that more efficiently yourself.  But if all the time is in the send method, it may be your mail server that's slow.

Comment: I placed some logs and the time is spent in the send(). It is unlikely to be a slow server because I tried sending the file from the filesystem with the same server and it was fast (anyway it takes ages for a small file to be sent via InputStream).

Comment: The InputStream is long gone by the time the sending is being done.  As I said, ByteArrayDataSource copies all the data immediately.  Try using a FileInputStream and the send should have the same performance as your InputStream.  If you're using a FileDataSource and seeing much better performance with the same amount of data, we need more details on how you're measuring the performance and how to reproduce the problem.  Try testing against (e.g.) Gmail to make sure it's not related to your server.

Comment: Did you try using a FileInputStream instead to see how the performance differs?  I don't know if you can do it with the wrapper class you're using, but instead of sending the message write it to a file using the MimeMessage.writeTo method to see what the performance of that is.  Turn on JavaMail Session debugging and watch the output.  If it takes 6 minutes to send the message, you might be able to see where in the process of sending it pauses for a long time.

Comment: If you write the message to a file instead of sending it, how long does that take?  Do you have an anti-virus or firewall program installed?  If you disable that, does the performance change?  If you just read your InputStream yourself, how long does it take?  Just to confirm, as in your code above, "attachment" is your InputStream and you're using ByteArrayDataSource, right?